# Android studio - Call to function from dll file or lib file

Tags: android, c, android-studio, dll, lib

I have a lib and dll files (I can choose which file I want to use)
I want to call to functions that are inside the file.
The code that complied in dll/lib wrote at c

Answer (score 1):

dll files (unless the dll is a dot.net dll and you are in a Xamarin app) are not usable in Android.

Furthermore DLL files typically are compiled for x86 (32bit) or x86_64 (64bit) CPUs. The number of Andorid devices with an x86 CPU is next to zero, for Android you need the library compiled for ARMv7 (32bit) and ARMv8 (64bit). As Android is  Linux based you need `.so` files in stead of `.dll` files.

To make development easier you should install Android Studio + Android NDK (Native Development Kit). Then you have everything for compiling c code in a way that you can make use of it within an Android app.

Google provides multiple sample projects that show how to use NDK: https://developer.android.com/ndk/samples

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
Someone else complied the code with visual studio.
I have the source code.
I will create so file.